# Can't read data out of XML stored in table column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have some data stored in a table in XML format:

```
<AccountTypes xmlns="">
  <Id>1003</Id>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Id>1004</Id>
  <Id>1002</Id>
  <Id>0</Id>
</AccountTypes>
```

This is legacy data that was previously only processed in C# code so can't be changed.

I now need to read this and process it in a stored procedure. So far I've got the following code:

```
DECLARE @accountTypes XML
SELECT @accountTypes = DT.AccountTypes FROM dbo.DataTable AS DT
WHERE DT.Id = 1016

DECLARE @hdoc int
    
EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @accountTypes
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/AccountTypes/Id')
WITH(
    Id VARCHAR(10) 'Id'
    )

EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

However the output from this is just rows of nulls:

```
Id
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

rather than the id values I was expecting.

I get the same results whether I include the `colpattern` ('Id') or not or whether I set the `flags` parameter on the `OPENXML` command.

Is there anything I can do with the data in it's current form to get the actual values out of the XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Id` is looking for a sub element of the `'/AccountTypes/Id'` nodes that is called `Id`

i.e. would match something in

```
<AccountTypes xmlns="">
  <Id>
    <Id>1003</Id>
  </Id>
</AccountTypes>
```

You can use

```
DECLARE @accountTypes XML
SELECT @accountTypes = '<AccountTypes xmlns="">
  <Id>1003</Id>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Id>1004</Id>
  <Id>1002</Id>
  <Id>0</Id>
</AccountTypes>'

DECLARE @hdoc int
    
EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @accountTypes;

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/AccountTypes/Id')
WITH(
    Id INT '.'
    )

EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Comment: Cheers. The annoying thing is that I'd started out with declaring Id as INT in the WITH statement but when that produced NULLs I thought it was due to the types being wrong so I went with VARCHAR instead. If I'd found the `colPattern` definition first I might have got there myself.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative way to get the data:

```
DECLARE @accountTypes XML
SELECT @accountTypes = DT.AccountTypes FROM dbo.DataTable AS DT
WHERE DT.Id = 1016

SELECT Id.value('.','int') AS Id
FROM @accountTypes.nodes('/AccountTypes/Id') AS Ids(Id)
```

This produces the same results and as the data I have is quite small runs in virtually the same time. There may be differences between the queries when run on larger XML.